# Errors running bitcoind in the background

Tags: bitcoind, error

I have installed bitcoind on a new computer, and I use `nohup` to run it:

```
$ nohup bitcoind &
```

However, every now and then I see that the process does not exist, and I have to restart it using `nohup`.

Any idea what went wrong? Are there any logs I can check, and is there a better way to run `bitcoind` in the background than `nohup`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bitcoind` has a `-daemon` command line option that will cause it to run in the background.  That is likely to work better than using `nohup`.

There should be a `debug.log` file in your bitcoin data directory where any errors will be logged.